# C# or asp.net or IIS can not access to save excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

**This is my function on C#**

```
public static void ExportToExcelAndDecode(this DataTable tbl, string excelFilePath)
    {
        try
        {
            if (tbl == null || tbl.Columns.Count == 0)
                throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Null or empty input table!\n");

            // load excel, and create a new workbook
            var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

            // single worksheet
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet workSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

            // column headings
            for (var i = 0; i < tbl.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                workSheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = tbl.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            }

            // rows
            for (var i = 0; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                // to do: format datetime values before printing
                for (var j = 0; j < tbl.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        workSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = new personnel.Tools.DataCoder().Decrypt(tbl.Rows[i][j].ToString());
                        
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            }
            // check file path
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(excelFilePath))
            {
                try
                {
                    workSheet.SaveAs(excelFilePath);
                    excelApp.Quit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath.\n"
                                        + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            { // no file path is given
                excelApp.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: \n" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

this code run and has not Error in my system but when publish to server page get this Error

> Error :ExportToExcel:  Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more
> documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space.
>
> • To make more memory available, close workbooks or programs you no
> longer need.
>
> • To free disk space, delete files you no longer need from the disk
> you are saving to.Hello World

i tested all link like this

[youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqvQ0JyBG2c)

[palisade.com](https://kb.palisade.com/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=1542)

[answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-cannot-open-or-save-any-more-documents/3ed44b45-2c20-4c9c-8598-16e7bd8e07b3)

[nothing](http://aminjavaheri.ir/index.aspx?lng=EN&postID=ec882cde-f5e6-438a-8d49-713689c9f1af)

i want use this assembly-> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Or if you have code to convert datatable to excel file

i need post excel byte to user

Comment: Don't walk any further on the wrong path, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

Comment: You can use `DocumentFormat.OpenXML`: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/

Comment: I tested your code on a window server. I'm afraid you can't use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to implement this function on the server. This requires Excel to be installed on the server, and Microsoft strongly discourages this.

Comment: I install Excel on my server to execute this code

Comment: Microsoft does not recommend you to do this, this is not the right way.

Comment: i know. but i must Create excel file in server. 
original question is ->
How can I convert datatable to excel in C#.
i get data from sql server in Datatable.then must convert to excel file and send to my user in web site.
Thanks for your tips.

Comment: The only way is to use DocumentFormat.OpenXML.

Comment: Thanks for your tips